# Does ConfigurationElementCollection preserve order

Tags: c#, config, app-config, configurationsection

I need to store a list of objects to a configuration section in their prioritized order.

If I go with the standard implementation of extending ConfigurationElementCollection and ConfigurationElement (similar to what is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.configuration.configurationcollectionattribute(v=vs.100).aspx)). Will the order of the collection be preserved when the config file is read from and written to?

Edit: Some sample code.

Given this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var section = config.GetSection("TestSection") as TestSection;
        foreach (MyElement item in section.HopefullyOrderedItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ElementValue);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class TestSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("ListOfThings")]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(MyCollection))]
    public MyCollection HopefullyOrderedItems
    {
        get { return (MyCollection) this["ListOfThings"]; }
        set { this["ListOfThings"] = value; }
    }

}

public class MyCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new MyElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((MyElement) element).ElementValue;
    }

    new public MyElement this[string name]
    {
        get { return (MyElement) BaseGet(name); }
    }
}

public class MyElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("ElementValue")]
    public string ElementValue
    {
        get { return (string) this["ElementValue"]; }
        set { this["ElementValue"] = value; }
    }
}
```

With this app.config:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="TestSection" type="testestes.TestSection, testestes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="true" />
    </configSections>
    <TestSection>
        <ListOfThings>
            <add ElementValue="qwerty" />
            <add ElementValue="asdfgh" />
        </ListOfThings>
    </TestSection>
</configuration>
```

When I access the list of things in code, is it guaranteed to be in the same order as specified in the config?

Comment: Even if it _did_, I would say requiring a specific order in the config file is a poor requirement (XML parsers are not required to preserve order, although most parsers return elements in the order they are found).